# OpenCL error "parameter may not be qualified with an address space"

Tags: opencl

I have the following OpenCL kernel code:

```
kernel void mandelbrot(global write_only image2d_t output_image)
{
    int2 pos = { get_global_id(0), get_global_id(1) };
    write_imageui(output_image, (int2)(pos.x, pos.y), (uint4)(254, 0, 0, 254));
}
```

When the program gets build, I get the following error message:

:1:52: error: parameter may not be qualified with an address space

:1:31: warning: Access qualifiers should only be applied to image types

OpenCL program build error code: -11

Can output images only be created as 1D arrays ?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need any address space qualifier for an image type.

OpenCL C specification 6.5.1:

> As image objects are always allocated from the global address space, the __global or global qualifier should not be specified for image types.

https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/specs/opencl-2.0-openclc.pdf